# Maven and IntelliJ resources

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

This seems like a simple problem but I seemingly can't find any solution or I don't understand some of the posts I read.

I have a Maven project with some resources, placed under the "/src/main/resources/" folder. Let it be a text.txt file. I have been told that any file I placed into that folder or into any folder declared in the pom.xml file will be placed in "/" (project root folder, you can see this when you unzip the stand alone jar file) after you have compiled it into a working jar.

So by that logic, I should be able to access the files via "text.txt" when Maven has package it into a jar. But doing so means that IntelliJ can't see the text file at "text.txt" because it is at "/src/main/resources/text.txt". Do I understand the packaging process corectly and which path I should put into my code?

Thank you in advanced.

---

Edit:

As some people pointed out, I need to be more specific about this.

So let's say I have my Main.java at src/main/java//Main.java and here is the code from it:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //stub
        System.out.println("Entered the program");
        File file=new File("src/main/resources/text.txt");
        System.out.println("String in text file: " + new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())));
    }
}
```

I also have the text.txt file at src/main/resources/text.txt

It compiled and run just fine when I press Shift+F10 (analogous to pressing the run button)

Here is part of my POM file:

```html
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.n157239.maven_rss.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And then I run `mvn clean compile assembly:single` so that Maven can produce a standalone jar file with dependancies in target/.

When I run the jar file from the command line, I get an error saying that there are no text.txt file.

Even when I changed the java code into `File file=new File("text.txt");`, it still gives an error when run the jar from the command line.

Comment: you can put your text files in yourproject/src/main/resources and your java code in yourproject/src/main/java have a look here https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: you need to go back and rewrite this question - What is it specifically that you want to ask? can you see a file once it has been packaged in a jar? Are you having issues seeing files in general?

Comment: Yes I already did that, but the question is what path to the text file should I choose so that it will work in both IntelliJ IDEA and in a jar packaged by using `maven clean compile assembly:single`

Comment: You shouldn't read anything from the `src` directory when running in production - assume the `src` directory doesn't even exist on the PC where your program is run. Use Lai's answer and you should be able to run in both IntelliJ and from the command line. Note that you can't open the file as a file, but rather open it directly as an InputStream using the class loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a file in `/src/main/resources/` you can read by just specifying the file name
`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("YourFile");`